# The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int, String

Tags: java, selenium

While compiling I am getting error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int, String
```

The error is in the **for loop**.

```
package automationFramework;

import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class DropDownMd {
    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.irctc.com/menu.html ");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Feedback")).click();
        WebElement Servcsdrop = driver.findElement(By.id("NU_SERVICE_ID"));

        Select Val = new Select(Servcsdrop);
        List<WebElement> Res = Val.getOptions();

        boolean f = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < Res.get(i).getText(); i++)
            // error is here

            if (Val.equals("TOURISM")) {
                f = true;
            }
        if (f) {
            System.out.println("tourism is present");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tourism is not present");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `Res.get(i).getText().length()`

Comment: And test Res.get(i).getText().equals("TOURISM"), not Val

Answer (score 5):

In your `for` loop, your condition for termination is that `i < Res.get(i).getText()`. The problem is that the second argument here is a `String`. You need a number in there. (Is 5 greater than or less than "banana"? The question doesn't make any sense.)

But I'm not sure what number, because I'm not clear on what your `for` loop is trying to achieve... better formatting would help (and probably help you too)...

Comment: I need to check the total number of values in the drop down and verify that 'Tourism' is selected in the drop down, If 'Tourism' is selected, output will be 'tourism is present'.

Answer (score 1):

well the error is self-explanatory. Here `for(int i=0; i < Res.get(i).getText(); i++)` you are checking if an `int` is ***less-than*** a `String`. I guess you want the text length so you should do:

`for(int i=0; i < Res.get(i).getText().length(); i++)`

If not then please specify what you are trying to do with your loop.

Comment: I need to check the total number of values in the drop down and verify that 'Tourism' is selected in the drop down, If 'Tourism' is selected, output will be 'tourism is present'.